# Web search algorithm with multiple words

Tags: algorithm, search, web

I want to use search from database on my website, so I think about effective algorithm to use. 
For example if I try to search "Hello my name is xxx" I want to see results:
**Hello my name is** John
**Hello my name is** Peter
**Hello** mr. **xxx**
His **name is** Peter
He **is** here

So I want to search all data from database with part of this text and sort result by number of matching words.

I made algorithm but I am pretty scared that it's so complicated and slow:
I split search text into words and use SQL select with multiple like or commands. Then I save this results into list. Then I count up numbers of matched words in each result and sort it by this count.
Problem is that when I will try to search long text.
Should I use better algorithm or should I learn somethink about thinks like Sphinx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first two results, a simple regex search should be able to retrieve results like that.
For the later ones, you might consider using an existing searching library thing, like [Google Search Appliance](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/), which can be used to search database information.